# how to disable mouse right click using python for windows

Tags: python

I'm working on a software in python for windows, and I need the mouse right click and left click to stop working sometimes . Can anyone help?

im new not use to writing copmelx apps and im not sure how to do thiss

Comment: write your code to ignore mouse clicks when required

Comment: well, I'm trying make a software that block all input from the keyboard and mouse this while it active.  but i can't find figure out how to disable either the mouse or keyboard